# WI FI adapter not found: Broadcom BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

I freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS but there is no WiFi icon. Upon searching manually I found the settings but still having WiFi adapter not found error.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4359]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [105b:e04b]
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Disable Secure Boot.

Comment: @Pilot6 No Possible I Don't know system password

Comment: Commiserations.